# How to retrieve all properties of Wikidata ordered by their usage using SPARQL

Tags: properties, sparql, wikidata

I found a query retrieving all properties of Wikidata together with property id, label, description and aliases

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>

SELECT ?p ?pt ?pLabel ?d ?aliases WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?p ?pt ?d
              (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?alias; separator="|") as ?aliases)
    WHERE {
      ?p wikibase:propertyType ?pt .
      OPTIONAL {?p skos:altLabel ?alias FILTER (LANG (?alias) = "en")}
      OPTIONAL {?p schema:description ?d FILTER (LANG (?d) = "en") .}
    } GROUP BY ?p ?pt ?d
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }
}
```

and a query counting properties used by items pointing to Q46 through a statement

```
SELECT ?property ?count
WHERE {
  SELECT ?property (COUNT(?item) AS ?count)
  WHERE {
    ?item ?statement wd:Q46 . # items pointing to Q46 through a statement
    ?property wikibase:statementProperty ?statement . # property used for that statement
  } GROUP BY ?property # count usage for each property pointing to that entity
} ORDER BY DESC(?count) # show in descending order of uses
```

I would combine them without depending on Q46 but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: something like this maybe? --   `SELECT ?property ?propertyLabel ?propertyAltLabel ?propertyDescription ?count
WHERE {
  {SELECT ?property (COUNT(?item) AS ?count)
  WHERE {
    ?item ?statement wd:Q46 .
    ?property wikibase:statementProperty ?statement .
  } GROUP BY ?property
             }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  }  
}
ORDER BY DESC(?count) `

Comment: @UninformedUser Well, the query should not depend on Q46 - this is a key issue. All existing statements should be taken into account.

Comment: and what is the final result then? the number of statements per property? I'm not sure where the issue is right now? I mean, if you do not want to depend on `wd:Q46`, why are you not replacing it by a variable? Clearly, this query will likely lead to a timeout for obvious reasons - it's a public shared service and there are hat, 9000 properties or something? and a patter `?s ?p ?o` is worst case scenario as no database index could be used.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest to get all properties first, then perform multiple queries  with maybe 50 or 100 properties per query given in a `VALUES` clause. So a small client side Python script would be my way to go.

Comment: @UninformedUser I need just property id, type, label, description and aliases as it is in the first query. Maybe count could be added but nothing about statements and items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such SPARQL query will take too much time leading to execution time out. The alternatives are:

1. Develop & use an application that

- unzip blocks of ~900 KiB from bzip2 archive of Wikidata JSON dump
  (https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/latest-all.json.bz2)
- pass that unzipped data from block to a JSON parser (it could be an event-driven JSON parser)
- parse that JSON extracting valuable data

2. Develop & use an application that

- reads bzip2 dump archive as described at point 1
- import parsed JSON data into an SQL database
- perform SQL queries on your own database extracting valuable data

3. Another way involving less development effort is:

- extract Wikidata JSON dump archive (~65 GiB) resulting an ~1.4 TB json file
- develop a small aplication that parse that type of json file using an event-driven parser
- parse that JSON extracting valuable data

Comment: PS I extracted myself those properties and I posted them on https://gist.github.com/cflaviu/e0bf0678f2ede69732b7131894f71031